# interchange sum and integral involving fourier series of x - [x] - 1/2

Tags: real-analysis

let $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{sin(2 \pi n x)}{\pi n}$ be the fourier series of $x - [x] -\frac{1}{2}
$

I want to show that for $-1<s<0$ I can interchange the integral and infinte sum:
$\int_{0}^{1} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{sin(2 \pi n x)}{\pi n} \frac{1}{x^{s+1}}dx$ =
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1}  \frac{sin(2 \pi n x)}{\pi n} \frac{1}{x^{s+1}} dx$

I was able to show that that $\alpha$ small enough $\int_{0}^{\alpha} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{sin(2 \pi n x)}{\pi n} \frac{1}{x^{s+1}}dx$ is small as I want

but I couldn't figure out how to do the same for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\alpha}  \frac{sin(2 \pi n x)}{\pi n} \frac{1}{x^{s+1}} dx$

doing this will solve my problem because the series converge uniformly for each compact set in $(0,1)$

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you integrate by parts:
$$ \int_{0}^{\alpha}  \frac{\sin(2 \pi n x)}{\pi n} \frac{1}{x^{s+1}} dx  = - \left[  \frac{\cos(2 \pi n x)-1}{2 \pi^2 n^2} \frac{1}{x^{s+1}}\right]_0^\alpha - (s+1) \int_{0}^{\alpha}  \frac{\cos(2 \pi n x)-1}{\pi^2 n^2} \frac{1}{x^{s+2}} dx $$
Also
$$ \int_{0}^{\alpha}  \frac{\cos(2 \pi n x)-1}{\pi^2 n^2} \frac{1}{x^{s+2}} dx = \int_{0}^{1/n}  \frac{\cos(2 \pi n x)-1}{\pi^2 n^2} \frac{1}{x^{s+2}} dx + \int_{1/n}^{\alpha}  \frac{\cos(2 \pi n x)-1}{\pi^2 n^2} \frac{1}{x^{s+2}} dx .$$
I think that each of these terms can be bounded to make their sum bounded and converge to zero as $\alpha\to 0$.

I don't have time to check it thoroughly, so tell me if it doesn't work, and I'll delete this answer.  If it works, give me a nice big green check mark.

Comment: $\frac{1}{x^{s+2}}$ diverges at zero

Comment: That's OK, because $|\cos(2\pi nx) - 1| \le C n^2 x^2$ for some constant $C > 0$.

Comment: You are right, and that solution seems fine to me

Comment: I looked at in again and I don't understand how it shows that the sum over n is small, I understand why each of the terms is small but how to show it for the sum?

Comment: You probably want to consider the two cases $\alpha > 1/n$ and $\alpha \le 1/n$ separately.  Then you estimate each term.  And then see that the sum of these terms is small.  I have a really busy day today, so I won't be able to spend time on it.  (The second displayed equation will only be used if $\alpha > 1/n$.)

Comment: Ok I'll check it. Thank you very much